# Finding BaseUrl in Module.php file in Zf2

Tags: zend-framework2, base-url

I need to find the baseUrl in my module.php file or my Service File. Earlier, I was using

```
                $event = $this->getEvent();
                $request = $event->getRequest();
                $router = $event->getRouter();
                $uri = $router->getRequestUri();
                $baseUrl = sprintf('%s://%s%s', $uri->getScheme(), $uri->getHost(), $request- >getBaseUrl());
```

But, I came to know this will run only in Controller's Action methods. How do I get baseUrl elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in `Module.php` -

```
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {

        $e->getApplication()
            ->getEventManager()
            ->getSharedManager()
            ->attach('*', 'route', array($this, 'some_function_name'));
    }

    public function some_function_name(MvcEvent $e) {
        $request = $e->getRequest();
        $router = $e->getRouter();
        $uri = $router->getRequestUri();
        $baseUrl = sprintf('%s://%s%s', $uri->getScheme(), $uri->getHost(),       $request->getBaseUrl());

        //[...some other code ... ]
    }

    //[...some other code ... ]
}
```